# Fetch new mail only while on Wifi (but not while on cellular data)

Tags: ios, settings, apns, mobile-mail

I'm using Mail on iOS 7.  I have it set to fetch new mail manually (only when I request it to fetch new mail; do not fetch automatically).

It would be nice if I could set things up to work differently when on Wifi then when on cellular data.  In particular, when on Wifi, it would be nice to fetch mail as often as possible, or to use push.  When on cellular data, I would prefer to stick to manual fetch only, to minimize use of cellular data.

Is there a way to do this?  I can't see a way to do this from within Settings >> Mail, Contacts, Calendars >> Fetch New Data.  Am I missing something, or is this simply not possible with the default Mail app?  Is there a third-party Mail app that offers this functionality?

Comment: Sadly the world has not caught on to this need yet.  I have 2 regular connections one is my flat rate unmetered wifi the other just like you is metered cellular.I very much want more than even just mail to have separate settings based on which connection is in use.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings app:

- Cellular

Turn of mail for using cellular data. (Swipe up to see the M section).  Unfortunately, this will disable all syncing over cellular data, and it will prevent you from even a manual fetch of email while on cellular data.  So, you'll need to twiddle with things whenever you want to do a manual fetch while on cellular data.

Comment: Interesting, this is helpful!  Unfortunately it prevents fetching mail even manually when on cellular data, so I'd have to flip to settings, toggle this, fetch mail, go back to settings, and re-toggle it (what a pain).  Consequently, it's less than ideal, to say the least... but maybe it's the best that can be done with the current system.  Thank you!

Comment: Yup. Also, you could just always have email be pull. Do you really need push notifications on wifi? That's an easier thing to manage for me if I had to choose..